# openSUSE 13.1 pam_ldap error trying to bind invalid credentials

Tags: authentication, openldap, pam, opensuse

Environment: new install of openSUSE 13.1 into a internal network of mostly 10.2 and 10.3 openSUSE. LDAP server (`@(#) $OpenLDAP: slapd 2.3.19 (Jul 28 2006 17:00:02)`) running on SUSE LE 10 .

Attempting to configure new 13.1 ldap client host ("main") using nss_ldap and pam_ldap (i.e., not using the SSSD). All older clients working fine w/ LDAP server.

Get following error when ssh to new host "main" (some info obsured) from older host "test":

```
    Sep 19 11:17:43 main sshd[10460]: Invalid user XXX from 10.3.0.72
    Sep 19 11:17:43 main sshd[10460]: input_userauth_request: invalid user XXX [preauth]
    Sep 19 11:17:43 main sshd[10460]: Postponed keyboard-interactive for invalid user XXX from 10.3.0.72 port 57170 ssh2 [preauth]
    Sep 19 11:17:47 main sshd[10462]: pam_ldap: error trying to bind as user "uid=XXX,ou=people,dc=XXX,dc=YYYY,dc=org" (Invalid credentials)
    Sep 19 11:17:47 main sshd[10460]: error: PAM: Authentication failure for illegal user XXX from test.blah.org
```

1. getent passwd XXX  -- returns nothing
2. getent group GGG - returns the ldap group info for known group GGG
3. `main:/etc # ldapsearch -x -L -u -t "(uid=XXX)"`  - returns the  LDAP info on user XXX

My /etc/pam.d/common-password is:

```
    password        requisite       pam_pwcheck.so  nullok cracklib remember=
    password        sufficient      pam_unix2.so    use_authtok nullok
    password        required        pam_ldap.so     try_first_pass use_authtok
```

My /etc/pam.d/common-auth is:

```
    auth    required        pam_env.so
    auth    sufficient      pam_unix2.so
    auth    required        pam_ldap.so     use_first_pass
```

What am I missing/forgetting?

Comment: forgot to add, here is ssh specific pam: main:/etc/pam.d # more sshd
        #%PAM-1.0
        auth     requisite      pam_nologin.so
        auth     include        common-auth
        account  include        common-account
        password include        common-password
        session  required       pam_loginuid.so
        session  include        common-session

Comment: for modify pam in suse, you can use pam-config command

Comment: Please edit your post when sharing the contents of config files, comments make them unreadable.

Answer (score 0):

Got resolution by adding "+::::::" to end of local files (passwd & shadow) --- now able to ssh to ldap-based accounts from the new openSUSE 13.1 host...but there surely must be something within my pams that is still wrong and this is just a kludge (?) Or does the openSUSE 13.1 install incorrectly not add that ending tag to the file?

Comment: PAM does not have anything to do with whether a user exists or not. If you found it necessary to add `+:`, it sounds like you're using NIS maps. As you did not share your NSS or LDAP configs with us, we can't give you any advice other than to look at those configs.